# Error while doing a simple count operation on spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have loaded a text file with data like this:

```
1   The Nightmare Before Christmas  1993    3.9 4568
2   The Mummy   1932    3.5 4388
3   Orphans of the Storm    1921    3.2 9062
4   The Object of Beauty    1991    2.8 6150
5   Night Tide  1963    2.8 5126
6   One Magic Christmas 1985    3.8 5333
7   Muriel's Wedding    1994    3.5 6323
8   Mother's Boys   1994    3.4 5733
9   Nosferatu: Original Version 1929    3.5 5651
10  Nick of Time    1995    3.4 5333
11  Broken Blossoms 1919    3.3 5367
12  Big Night   1996    3.6 6561
13  The Birth of a Nation   1915    2.9 12118
14  The Boys from Brazil    1978    3.6 7417
```

step1:
Used the following command:

```
//Loaded into rdd
val rddLoad = sc.textFile("/user/rahulm.3564_gmail/IMDB_DATA.txt");
//Split based on commas since it is a comma separated file
val rddLoadSplit = rddLoad.map(_.split(','))
```

step2:
Then created a DataFrame like this:

```
case class MovieData(serialNo:Int, movieName:String, releaseYear:Int, rating:Double, runningTime:Int);

val dfSchema = rddLoadSplit.map {case Array(serialNo, movieName, releaseYear, rating, runningTime) => MovieData(serialNo.toInt, movieName, releaseYear.toInt,  rating.toDouble, runningTime.toInt)}.toDF();
```

Step4: dfSchema.show gives proper result:

```
scala> dfSchema .show

only showing top 20 rows
```

Step4:

now when I do a dfSchema.count, I get errors as follows:

```
17/08/28 11:36:24 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 47, i
p-172-31-58-214.ec2.internal): scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@62202bc4 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:34)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:34)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:505)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.<init>(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:686)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: is your data comma delimited or tab delimited? your data seems tab delimited but your code says its comma delimited, why?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because data contains malformed rows which don't follow expected format and pattern matching fails with `scala.MatchError` here:

```
{case Array(serialNo, movieName, releaseYear, rating, runningTime) => MovieData(serialNo.toInt, movieName, releaseYear.toInt,  rating.toDouble, runningTime.toInt)}
```

I'd use `PartialFunction` with `collect` (you may still have to handle exceptions during casting):

```
rddLoadSplit.collect {
  case Array(serialNo, movieName, releaseYear, rating, runningTime) => MovieData(serialNo.toInt, movieName, releaseYear.toInt,  rating.toDouble, runningTime.toInt)
}.toDF();
```

or `csv` reader with appropriate `delimiter` and `mode` set to `DROPMALFORMED`"

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("/user/rahulm.3564_gmail/IMDB_DATA.txt")
```